# Selenium WebDriver - Element being found repeatedly went stale

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, jenkins

Sometimes am getting the following error When i am running the test in Jenkins.
But test is passing in local VM without this error.

ERROR MESSAGE :
**Element being found repeatedly went stale, is it being repeatedly modified by javascript, or is it in a list of elements (see the package-info.java in WebDriverWrapper for more details)?**

But finding element by id is different for all the elements. But still am getting this error.
Can you please anyone explain why this error occurs and what is the solution for this?